# How to remove coolrom.com malware from ubuntu?

Tags: malware

I've been dumb and downloaded the malware from coolrom that inputs some sort of """search engine""" in firefox. I'm trying everything to clean that but without success. Someone knows how should I do it?

Comment: Check your Firefox extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To get rid of it, click on the three horizontal lines (top right) -> Add-ons -> Extensions. Find Coolrom then remove. Goodluck